# How to reason with complex pattern-matchings?

Tags: coq

Coq allows to write complex pattern-matchings, but then it decomposes them so that its kernel can handle them.

For instance, let us consider the following code.

```
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.

Inductive bar := A | B | C.

Definition f (l : list bar) :=
  match l with
  | _ :: A :: _ => 1
  | _ => 2
  end.
```

We pattern-match both on the list and on the second element. Printing `f` shows that Coq stores a more complex version of it.

```
Print f.
(* f = fun l : list bar => match l with
                        | [] => 2
                        | [_] => 2
                        | _ :: A :: _ => 1
                        | _ :: B :: _ => 2
                        | _ :: C :: _ => 2
                        end
     : list bar -> nat
*)
```

The problem is that, in the proofs manipulating `f`, I have to deal with 5 cases instead of only 2, and 4 of them are redundant.

What is the best way to deal with this? Is there a way to reason with the pattern-matching as if it were exactly as defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that Coq actually *simplifies* pattern-matching making a lot of redundancies appear.
There are however some ways to reason on the case analysis you **meant** opposed to what Coq understands.

- Using `Function` and [function induction](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.function-induction) is a way.
- More recently, [Equations](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/) also allows you to define pattern-matching for which it derives induction principles automatically (that you can invoke using `funelim`).
  In order to convince coq cases can be factorised you have to use the notion of view.
  They are described in the context of Equations [in the examples](http://mattam82.github.io/Coq-Equations/examples/Examples.views.html).
  I'll detail how to adapt your example to it.

```
From Equations Require Import Equations.
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.

Inductive bar := A | B | C.

Equations discr (b : list bar) : Prop :=
  discr (_ :: A :: _) := False ;
  discr _ := True.

Inductive view : list bar -> Set :=
| view_foo : forall x y, view (x :: A :: y)
| view_other : forall l, discr l -> view l.

Equations viewc l : view l :=
    viewc (x :: A :: y) := view_foo x y ;
    viewc l := view_other l I.

Equations f (l : list bar) : nat :=
    f l with viewc l := {
    | view_foo _ _ => 1 ;
    | view_other _ _ => 2
    }.

Goal forall l, f l < 3.
Proof.
    intro l.
    funelim (f l).
    - repeat constructor.
    - repeat constructor.
Qed.
```

As you can see, `funelim` only generates two subgoals.

It can be a bit heavy so if you don't want to use Equations of Function, you might have to prove your own induction principles by hand:

```
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.

Inductive bar := A | B | C.

Definition f (l : list bar) :=
  match l with
  | _ :: A :: _ => 1
  | _ => 2
  end.

Definition discr (l : list bar) : Prop :=
    match l with
    | _ :: A :: _ => False
    | _ => True
    end.

Lemma f_ind :
    forall (P : list bar -> nat -> Prop),
        (forall x y, P (x :: A :: y) 1) ->
        (forall l, discr l -> P l 2) ->
        forall l, P l (f l).
Proof.
    intros P h1 h2 l.
    destruct l as [| x [|[] l]].
    3: eapply h1.
    all: eapply h2.
    all: exact I.
Qed.

Goal forall l, f l < 3.
Proof.
    intro l.
    eapply f_ind.
    - intros. repeat constructor.
    - intros. repeat constructor.
Qed.
```